# Wrapper for CultureInfo

Tags: c#, cultureinfo

I would like to create a wrapper class to replace the CultureInfo base class. For example; in my code I have

```
var cultureInfo = new CultureInfo (stringVariableForCultureName);
```

I would like to replace that line for this other:

```
var cultureInfo = new CultureInfoWrapper (stringVariableForCultureName);
```

The reason is that I don't have control of the value passed to initialize the CultureInfo and I want to avoid the error exception defaulting the CultureInfo

So my CultureInfoWrapper constructor should be something like:

```
public CultureInfoWrapper(string cultureName)
{
    try
    {
        return new CultureInfo(cultureName);
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {   
        return new CultureInfo(DefaultCultureName);
    }
}
```

Can you help me to define the wrapper class?

Comment: Catching exceptions like in your code above looks like a bad idea to me, since you are using exceptions to control program flow. Exceptions are bad for the performance of your application.

Comment: Constructors don't *return* a value of the new type (and in your example, it's returning a value of a different type), so your plan is heading in the wrong direction to start with.

Comment: I agree wth you @UweKeim . I could check also if the string passed is a valid CultureInfo name, but still I will need my original request which is can I create the wrapper for the CultureInfo class.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Damien_The_Unbeliever . I know that, that is why I am struggling here

Comment: Why do you want to use a wrapper *class*? It looks like all you need is a `CultureInfo`-returning *method*.

Comment: It was just an idea Pieter Witvoet

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use this implementation, note that i've handled the `CultureNotFoundException`:

```
public class CultureInfoWrapper
{
    private readonly CultureInfo _cultureInfo;

    public CultureInfo Value
    {
        get { return _cultureInfo; }
    }

    public CultureInfoWrapper(string cultureName, string fallbackCultureName = "en-US")
    {
        try
        {
            _cultureInfo = new CultureInfo(cultureName);
        }
        catch (CultureNotFoundException)
        {
            _cultureInfo = new CultureInfo(fallbackCultureName);
        }
    }
}
```

Another approach would be to load all cultures once, then you can use this optimized version:

```
public class CultureInfoFinder
{
    private static readonly CultureInfo DefaultCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");

    private static Dictionary<string, CultureInfo> _allSpecificCultures;

    static CultureInfoFinder()
    {
        _allSpecificCultures = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.SpecificCultures)
            .ToDictionary(c => c.ToString(), c => c, StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
    }

    public static CultureInfo Get(string cultureName)
    {
        CultureInfo c;
        bool knownCulture = _allSpecificCultures.TryGetValue(cultureName, out c);
        return knownCulture ? c : DefaultCulture;
    }
}
```

For example:

```
CultureInfo deDE = CultureInfoFinder.Get("de-DE");
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Tim Schmelter

Comment: @SergioKastro: i've added another approach which doesn't need try-catch

Comment: Even better ;-)